# How can I match this with a regex ? C#

Tags: c#, .net

I wanna match with a regex everything between 2 strings.

The input text is like this:

```
 Back to previous › 






             › Send Message 

                             › Add as Buddy 
             › Add as Favorite 
             › Block this Person 





         People who like this (click to upvote)
```

I wanna match everything between **Back to previous >** and **People who like this (click to upvote)**.

I tried the easiest regex which is `(?<=\ Back\ to\ previous\ ›\ ).*(?=People\ who\ like\ this\ profile\ \(click\ to\ upvote\)\ )` but no luck with it.

The ideea is to catch everything between 2 lines\strings, even thought what you catch is newline, tab, alphanumeric, and so on.

Comment: You have no word "page" in text, but you have it in regex

Comment: sorry, edited. Still that's not the problem.

Comment: "." in .net is any symbol, exept \n

Comment: Try setting multiline http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.100).aspx#Multiline

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

**(?<=Back\sto\sprevious.*?›).?(?=People\swho\slike\sthis)**

```
string Input = @"Back to previous › 






         › Send Message 

                         › Add as Buddy 
         › Add as Favorite 
         › Block this Person 





     People who like this (click to upvote) ";
        foreach (Match M in Regex.Matches(Input, @"(?<=Back\sto\sprevious.*?›).*?(?=People\swho\slike\sthis)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(M.Value.Trim());
        }
```

This displays following in the message box:

```
› Send Message 



                         › Add as Buddy 

         › Add as Favorite 

         › Block this Person
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have your string delimiters (e.g. "Back to Previous") on different lines you have no reason of using Regexes:

```
string text = /* Get Text */;
string lines = text.Split();
IEnumerable<string> content = lines.Skip(1).Take(lines.length - 2);
```

Or alternatively:

```
const string matchStart = "Back to previous >";
const string matchEnd = "People who like this (click to upvote)"
int beginIndex = text.IndexOf(matchStart) + matchStart.Length;
int endIndex = text.IndexOf(matchEnd);
string content = text.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex);
```

(The code I've posted is not tested but it should work)

Comment: I am actually using a software which is called zennoposter (which is made in c#\.net), and the regex is the same. That's why I need regex ...

Comment: @andreimiko: I think if you can solve your problem without using regex do it. Because it's hard to read it and harder to fix it later.